# Installing php-gd on godaddy vps server on ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, putty

I was working on localhost with resizing images and everything was great. Than I uploaded to my server and things got interesting. After searching around, looks like I have to enable php-gd on my server.

I tried running the line `sudo apt-get install php5-gd` using putty, and it didn't work.
Any ideas why?

Also, after the install, I assume I will need to run the function `sudo reboot` right? clearly I'm not an expert in this area :p

Comment: Try enabling the module and restart Apache... `sudo php5enmod gd && sudo service apache reload`